# Why is React Router location props only available in Context?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a react-app (v16.4.2) with react-router-dom (v4.3.1). After I define a Link and pass state as part of that link that information is only available in Context and not in props. Whats happening? How can I access the info in context? Or move route info to props?

Index.JS

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./components/App";
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import history from "./components/common/History";

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history}><App /></Router>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.JS

```
import ReportInfo from './reporting/ReportInfo';
import FacilityContactsForm from "./facilities/FacilityContactsForm";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const store = init();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div>
             <Header />
            <div className="container-fluid">
          <Route exact path="/" component={FacilitySearch} />
          <Route exact path="/facilities" render={() => <FacilitySearch {...this.props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/facilities/:id" render={(props) => <FacilityInfo id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/facilities/contacts/:id" render={(props) => <FacilityContactsForm id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/facilities/permits/:id" render={(props) => <PermitInfo id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/facilities/reports/:id" render={(props) => <ReportInfo id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} />} />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

}
}

```
export default App;
```

Code I'm passing:

```
return <div className="information">
            <Button className="btn btn-block contacts-btn " onClick={() => this.toggle()}>Facility Landowner</Button>
            <div id="demo" className={"collapse" + (this.state.open ? ':not(.show)' : '')}>

                <div className="information">
                    No Landowner information exists for this facility. <Link to={{
                        pathname: `/facilities/contacts/${this.props.id}`,
                        state: { facilityName: this.props.facility.facilityName }
                    }}
                        className="hyperlinks"> Create A New Contact</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

React Tool View:

[image: React Dev Tools Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While rendering a component using `render props method` you need get the `router` props as an argument in the callback function. You need to pass that down to the component to access Router props as props in the component

```
class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
              <div>
                 <Header />
                <div className="container-fluid">
              <Route exact path="/" component={FacilitySearch} />
              <Route exact path="/facilities" render={(props) => <FacilitySearch {...this.props} {...props} />} />
              <Route exact path="/facilities/:id" render={(props) => <FacilityInfo id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props}  {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/facilities/contacts/:id" render={(props) => <FacilityContactsForm id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} {...props} />} />
              <Route exact path="/facilities/permits/:id" render={(props) => <PermitInfo id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/facilities/reports/:id" render={(props) => <ReportInfo id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} {...props} />} />
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it doesn't appear to work for me. I added routerProps to the `facilities/contacts/:id` route but sill get the same results. `<Route exact path="/facilities/contacts/:id" render={(props, routerProps) => <FacilityContactsForm id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} {...routerProps} />} />`

Comment: @rralbritton you will write it like `render={(routerProps) => <FacilityContactsForm id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} {...routerProps} />}`  and not how you showed

Comment: I'm not following. I can't take out the `(props)`, otherwise these statements within the route, `id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props}`, props is undefined. With that said, if I remove all references to props and make it just say `<Route exact path="/facilities/contacts/:id" render={(routerProps) => <FacilityContactsForm {...routerProps} />} />`  then yes, it works but I need access to the props as well. How can I achieve both?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I named the arguments as routerProps but instead you can simply spread props. `render={(props) => <FacilityContactsForm id={props.match.params.id} {...this.props} {...props} />}`

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much